# Custom Configuration Files

Tags: configuration, development, testing

We have an issue in which we would want different sets of configuration settings to be used on development, test, and production servers. I'm just getting familiar with Magento and not sure how to do this - what's the standard way of accomplishing this?

Something like:

```
- etc/* // used for production mode
- etc/test/* // used for test mode
- etc/dev/* // used for development mode
```

... and then we could set the mode `SetEnv` in htaccess (as for with "developer mode"). Does Magento have built-in support for this?

Answer (score 2):

## All `*.xml` files in `etc` are loaded

Be careful if you place different files `prod.xml`, `dev.xml`, etc. in your etc folder because they are all loaded, in the order:

```
local.xml
all others
local.xml
```

## Deployment

I recommend to put all the config files somewhere else, like `var/deploy` or `/deploy` and then copy them over via a deployment script (which you hopefully use :-))